# Likelihood ratio test for random intercept (MATLAB)

Tags: statistical-significance, mixed-model, likelihood-ratio

I need to program a likelihood ratio test for testing the significance of a random effect in a linear mixed model in MATLAB. But I am having some trouble finding out how to correctly specify the null model.

Here is the code for the full model:

```
model_h1 = fitlmematrix(X, y, Z, G);
```

where `X` is the fixed effect design matrix, `y` is the response vector, `Z` is a column vector of ones with length equal to the number of rows in `X`, and G is a grouping variable for the random effect. Here is the model formula written in `fitlme` syntax:

```
model_h1 = fitlme(data, y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + (1|G))
```

My goal is to test the significance of the random intercept term `(1|G)`, for example using the `compare` method (e.g. `compare(model_h0, model_h1)`). But what would be the correct syntax for the null model here? Intuitively I would guess the null model should be a model with the fixed effects included, without the random intercept (a general linear model). But I don't think this would be supported by the `compare` function. Is there a way of generating a `LinearMixedModel` object which does not include any random effects?

Comment: Why do you want to test the significance of the random intercepts? This is generally a bad idea.

Comment: I agree, I'm only doing it because I wrote a function intended to reproduce some results, and I need to know whether my code is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way of generating a LinearMixedModel object which does not include any random effects?

I am not a MATLAB expert, and programming questions are off-topic here anyway (so you might try asking that on a MATLAB programming site), but a model without random effects is not a mixed effects model, so from that point of view it may not be possible.

The standard approach with a platform such as R is simply to fit the the linear model and compare that to the mixed model directly with a likelihood ratio test (since these are nested models)

```
model1 <- lmer(Y ~ X + (1|G), mydata)
model2 <- lm(Y ~ X, mydata)
anova(model1, model2)
```

However, the LRT of a variance parameter equalling zero is conservative (larger p-value). This is due to the test being on a boundary condition, since a variance cannot be negative). In linear mixed models with a single random intercept term, this p-value is approximately twice as large as it should be.

Other options for testing the significance of a random effect are profiled confidence intervals, the [exact LRT test](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.15.1447&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and the parametric bootstrap.

Comment: I see, so in R you can simply compare a GLM and a LMM directly using the anova function. I am probably misunderstanding, but should the formula for your model2 include the (1|G)?

Comment: Right ! Thanks for spotting the typo!